# How to remove a parent node with all its children

Tags: javascript

I am learning the basics of javascript. now it DOM and i am stuck here, How can i remove a parent node with all its chldren. eg say i have the html code like this.

```
<ul id ="parent">
    <li>Hi</li>
    <li>How</li>
    <li>Are</li>
    <li>You</li>
</ul>
```

i wand to delete the `<ul>` element with all its child `<li>` nodes. I tried it to do like this `document.getElementById('parent').removeNode(true);` but its not working. Can anyone help me here. ?

Comment: Jquery might be helpful if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for ur attention, I am interesting in learning Javascript and not bound to do the task.. Well i am looking for a javascript method..

Comment: @Ajinkya - Don't try to talk somebody out of "plain" JavaScript. Yes, jQuery is great, but a little understanding of how the DOM really works is never a bad thing.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes completely agree. I just said to have a look (it should be after knowing JAvascript). Apologies if I am misguiding. (I think I am in love with Jquery)

Comment: Suggesting the OP use a 4,000 line library to do something that takes one line of script is not sensible. And given that the OP is trying to learn basic javascript, it's particularly unhelpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to get a handle to the `ul` element then ask its parent element to delete it by passing the `ul` handle the parent's `removeChild` method.

This is how you would do it without the jQuery framework:

```
var x = document.getElementById('parent');
x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
```

Of course if you used jQuery it would be simple like this:

```
$("#parent").remove();
```

Comment: @Arman Thanks a lot It works, but is It Necessary to use a variable x here, Can we do it without it..

Comment: @Showket, yes you can. I just broke it into two steps so to make it easy to read. You should do it the way you find comfortable to read.

Comment: @eureka, technically he knows javascript. He just needs to know how to manipulate the DOM using JavaScript. Thus I tried to show him different alternatives.

Comment: @Showket - you need the `x` variable because otherwise you have to repeat the whole `document.getElementById('parent')` - notice `x` appears twice on the second line.

Comment: @nnnnnn, the code can be written like this so to ignore having to use the `x` variable: `document.getElementById('parent').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('parent'));`

Comment: Isn't that what I just said? (Or at least implied?)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
var childNode = document.getElementById("parent");
childNode.parentNode.removeChild(childNode);
```

Comment: Might want to declare `childNode` with `var` so that you don't create a global variable.

Comment: this only removes the child node but the parent node stays like<ul><li></li></ul>
li gets deleted but <ul></ul> stays