# for each element javascript remove parent div and replace with own div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove the parent div's for each input class with javascript and replace them with my own classes. However the id's of the input fields are always random. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var filter = document.getElementsByName('filter[]');

function show() {
    for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
        alert(filter[i].value)
    }
}

//The .sidebar-filter-item, should not be hardcoded 
//because that name can differ always. 
$("<h2> test </h2>").insertBefore(".sidebar-filter-item ");
```

Here is how my input fields look like:

```
<div class="random1293">
    <input id="filter_16" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="16">
</div>

<div class="random2423">
    <input id="filter_17" type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="17">
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571512/how-to-remove-a-parent-node-with-all-its-children stuff like that, except that is all hard codes removal of div's, i don't know how to make the syntax so that it works with my problem.

Comment: It is still unclear what you want to archive. You have input fields and each of this fields is wrapped in a div, which you want to remove, right?. And where do you want to add your class?

Comment: The divs around every input field must be replaced with my own. But the names of those div's can vary

Comment: @NickAudenaerde are you saying that you want to change the parent `div` class of all the inputs??

Comment: yes @Reddy that's exactly what im saying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you have not tagged this post as Jquery but still used jquery in your code in the OP, I conclude that Jquery solution is acceptable.

Select all the input elements which start with the id `filter_` and then change the class of the parent div to what ever you want.

```
$('input[id^="filter_"]').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().attr('class','yourOwnClassHere');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @NickAudenaerde there was a small typo.. I had typed `filtter_` instead of `filter_`. Now I have fixed it have a check..

Comment: still doesn't seem to do anything =/

Answer (score 2):

Once selected you can select a DOM elements parent element using:

```
element.parentElement
```

Regarding selecting the elements if the id attributes are going to be random/unpredictable you could instead use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Which will give you an array of all your input elements which you can then loop through to perform your operation to each.

Alternatively you could give each of the elements you want selected a class (if you don't want all inputs on the page) an use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("className");
```

which will also return an array which you can handle in the same fashion.

Comment: This option still doesn't allow me to change the div's into the div's i want them to change into.

Comment: Well if you have the input sected in this way you can add a class using an operation like `input.className += " otherclass";` Is this what you mean?